# Store data in shared dictionary with multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to use the Pool class of the multiprocessing module to run several geospatial calculations on multiple cores simultaneously. I want the results to be written in a dictionary that I can subsequently use to do some further stuff with. The input coordinates are stored in a csv file and every single pair of coordinates is stored as a tuple for the map function to work.

So far I have this:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def some_function(point_coords):
    result = f"do some stuff with {point_coords}"

if __name__ == '__main__':

    csv_file= r'C:\Users\Name\Desktop\csv_file.csv'

    with open(csv_file, newline='') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        pointlist = list(reader)

    list1=[]
    list2=[]
    for i in pointlist:
        list1.append(i[0])
        list2.append(i[1])
    point_coords_zip = zip(list1,list2)
    point_coords = set(point_coords_zip)

    p = Pool()
    mapping = p.map(some_function, point_coords)

    p.close()
    p.join()
```

I simply want the `some_function()` to create the `point_coords` as the key and the `result` as a value in a dictionary for each job. I have read about the Manager class. But I am not sure how I can use `dict = manager.dict()` to store all the results.

Comment: You canot share one dictionary between multiple processes.

Comment: You cannot do it easily. Why multiprocessed and not threads (this shares memory)? Or you can just have a master, which collect the data and distribute it. Or just every process could use a common file (with lock) to share data (and regularly read data)

Comment: Im using multiprocessing instead of threading since there are lots of CPU intensive geospatial computations going on within the `some_function()`. Is there maybe a way to create a dictionary within each process and then somehow collect the output (the dictionary) of each process? Otherwise every process would have to write in the same file it's output. I am trying to avoid the additional time needed for writing into a file.